# Camel JMS CXF endpoints doesn't create new temp reply queue

Tags: soap, jms, cxf, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have two CXF endpoints which use JMS as the transport; one is used as a consumer and the second as a producer. Here is a very trimmed down setup.

```
<camelcxf:cxfEndpoint xmlns:i="http://inbound.com/inbound"
                      id="myInboundEndpoint"
                      endpointName="i:InboundService"
                      serviceName="i:InboundService"
                      address="camel://direct:my-inbound-route"
                      serviceClass="com.InboundService"
                      bus="cxf"
                      wsdlURL="classpath:META-INF/wsdl/inbound.wsdl">
    <camelcxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO"/>
    </camelcxf:properties>
</camelcxf:cxfEndpoint>

<camelcxf:cxfEndpoint xmlns:o="http://outbound.com/outbound"
                      id="myOutboundEndpoint"
                      endpointName="o:OutboundService"
                      serviceName="o:OutboundService"
                      address=""jms://"" 
                      serviceClass="com.OutboundService"
                      bus="cxf"
                      wsdlURL="classpath:META-INF/wsdl/outbound.wsdl">
    <camelcxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO"/>
    </camelcxf:properties>
    <camelcxf:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfigFeature">
            <property name="jmsConfig" ref="jmsConfig" />
        </bean>
    </camelcxf:features>
</camelcxf:cxfEndpoint>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="targetDestination" value="some-queue" />
</bean>

<camelContext>
    <route id="inQueue">
        <from uri="activemq:inbound-queue" />
        <to uri="direct:my-inbound-route" />
    </route>
    <route id="inVm">
        <from uri="direct:in-vm" />
        <to uri="direct:my-inbound-route" />
    </route>
    <route id="serviceProxy">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:myInboundEndpoint?synchronous=true" />
        <setHeader headerName="operationName"><constant>myOtherOperation</constant></setHeader>
        <to uri="cxf:bean:outboundEndpoint?synchronous=true" />
    </route>        
</camelContext>
```

But what happens when the second route is called is that CXF component or camel tries to re-use all the JMS config from the original inbound message including the reply queue rather than creating another temp reply queue just for this exchange. This seems to be taken of the headers from the in message.

If you just use pure JMS and take CXF out of the equation then camel correctly creates a new queue for the inner part of the route although I need to continue to use CXF as there are some legacy interceptors I'm bound to use.

I have tried both using the jms:// + JMSConfig style as well as the camel:// style.

I am currently using the jaxws:client approach and just referencing using bean:myBean?method=myMethod which works but doesn't allow me to propagate SOAP headers from the original inbound method hence switching to use cxf:endpoint instead.

I have tried to find an example of someone using SOAP over JMS using CXF and there seems to be no concrete examples.

So the question is.... is there any additional configuration I need to do for my producer or is there some otherway I can do SOAP over JMS using CXF and propagate/set some headers from the original message/camel exchange?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to filter the header of replyTo from the inMessage.

If you want to use SOAP over JMS, you can specify all the JMS related setting on the address without hacking the JMSConfiguration. Here is the [document](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/soap-over-jms-10-support.html) that you can take as an example.

Comment: Hi Willem, I tried stripping the JMS* headers. Are there some other headers I should strip? maybe camel specific ones?

Comment: Actually we also tried stripping all headers to no effect. BTW I got the JMSConfig style from the camel docs. Could be worth an update if there is a preferred method. Presumably you set the POJO/PAYLOAD on the CXF component options and connection pool using the URI?

Comment: Can you just write the simple CXF client to verify the setting? I just check the CXF code, if you don't set ReplyToDestination on the JMSConfig, the CXFJmsConduit won't call the jmsMessage.setJMSReplyTo for it. So I'm not sure the what kind of  reply queue that you mentioned.

Comment: If I use the cxf client then it works fine but as I am just talking to a Java interface I can't set the custom SOAP headers right? That needs to be done with a CXF interceptor which doesn't have access to the camel context. Or have I got the wrong end of the stick? I thought the default behavior if you didn't set a replyToName was to create a temp queue automatically?

Comment: I guess the issue could be caused by sharing the same configuration of activemq connection between camel and cxf endpoint. Can you try to configure the cxf endpoint and camel activemq separately.